# Engine sound louder when accelerated from 20mph - Nissan Altima 2015

Tags: engine, transmission, maintenance, nissan, altima

I bought a Nissan Altima 2015 and its been 18 months since I am using it and have around 17000 miles on my car. Recently I started experiencing engine sound louder than expected when accelerated to 40 mph. Rpm rises upto 3-4000 mph and drastically drops to 1500mph when accelerated at 20mph to 40mph. Is there an issue with Nissan Altima or how do I address this?

Comment: Is there a "sport" button or setting for the transmission that would cause it to shift later than usual?